# Vlasov equation why "long range" interactions?

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

In discussions of the Vlasov equation it is often said (e.g. Cercignani, 1988; pg59) that we require rarefied gas with weak, long range interactions. I understand why we need weak interactions (since we take a scaling of $1/N$ for the force) but I can't see why we need the interaction to be long range.

Does anyone know why this is so? (a source would be helpful).

Comment: Lifshitz and Pritaevskii (volume 10) go into this (pg116-117)

Comment: You can see this article on the history of the Vlasov equation: it is just the Boltzmann equation with no collision integral, that should drop to zero because for long-range interactions the concept of "binary collision" is not relevant anymore: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1982A%26A...114..211H/abstract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand why we need weak interactions (since we take a scaling of 1/N for the force) but I can't see why we need the interaction to be long range.

It is one of the assumptions required to create a limit where the [Boltzmann collision operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation) goes to zero.  More importantly, the physical reason they state as much is because the fluids handled by the [Vlasov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation) are typically ionized gases, namely plasmas.  In a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)), the particles are charged and respond to the collective fields of all the charged particles out to infinity (in principle/theory, but generally [Debye shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length) and quasi-neutrality keep the interactions more local).

> Does anyone know why this is so?

The only real difference between the Boltzmann and Vlasov equations are the lack of a collision operator in the latter, namely, that the latter is considered [time-reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_reversibility).  Using things like [ensemble averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_average_(statistical_mechanics)) (e.g., [mean field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory)) can change the Vlasov equation from a time-reversible to a time-irreversible equation, but that is an additional nuance.

> In discussions of the Vlasov equation it is often said (e.g. Cercignani, 1988; pg59) that we require rarefied gas with weak, long range interactions.

If the **particle-particle** interactions (e.g., [Coulomb collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision)) are strong, then the Vlasov equation is no longer the appropriate approximation to use and requires a collision operator.